# How can I set locales in /etc/defaults/locale?

Tags: locale

Set `/etc/defaults/locale` to:

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8" 
LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8 
LC_ALL="en_GB.UTF-8" 
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8" 
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8" 
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8" 
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8" 
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8" 
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8" 
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8" 
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8" 
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
```

It's from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/126994-locale-system-error?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com).

Can anyone help to apply it to my system?

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo localectl set-locale LANG=en_GB.utf8
```

Or if you want to do it manually open that file using an editor like `nano`:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/locale
```

paste that lines into this file then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save the file, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit.

If you prefer graphical tools then run:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/locale
```

Paste the lines and save the file.

Comment: thanks , i did it by nano as you said in the second way , but the main problem didn't solved it still give me this error when i try to install the software"  RuntimeError: locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid"

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100708/mongodb-mongorestore-failure-localefacet-s-create-c-locale-name-not-valid